# trying to get feedback when debugging with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, rspec

I am building a function to build an manipulate a linked list in ruby. right now I am working on the `delete` method and trying to include puts statements in the rspec tests to confirm my assumptions as I am programming.

The variables I am looking to have show up are `@head`, `examined_node`,`examined_node.next` `@head.next`, `after_examined_node`, `@tail`. Really I feel like if someone could help explain or point me in a good article as to how to extract one the others should follow.

this is the specific block in my spec file that fails along with a smattering of code I tried to use to get some feedback. I should note I tried these one by one but uncommented them here.

```
  it "removes the head of a list properly" do
      llist.delete(n1)

      puts @head
      puts self.examined_node.data
      puts examined_node
      puts @tail

      expect(llist.head).to eq n2 #Breaks here
      expect(llist.head.next).to eq n3
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n3
    end
```

Here is my `node.rb` file

```
class Node 
  attr_accessor :next
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    @next = nil
  end
end
```

Here are the pertinent parts of my `linked_list.rb` file

```
require_relative 'node'

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head
  attr_accessor :tail

  attr_accessor :current
  attr_accessor :bob
  def initialize(*args)
    @current = nil
    @bob = []
  end
  # This method creates a new `Node` using `data`, and inserts it at the end of the list.
   def add_to_tail(node)

    if(@tail)
      @tail.next = node
      @tail = node
    else
      @head = node
      @tail= node
    end
  end
def delete(node)
    examined_node = @head
    after_examined_node = @head.next
  end
```

This is a bit more of my `Rspec` file

```
include RSpec

require_relative 'node'
require_relative 'linked_list'

RSpec.describe LinkedList, type: Class do
  let(:n1) { Node.new("Rob") }
  let(:n2) { Node.new("Ben") }
  let(:n3) { Node.new("Mike") }
  let(:llist) { LinkedList.new }
  describe "#delete" do
    before do
      llist.add_to_tail(n1)
      llist.add_to_tail(n2)
      llist.add_to_tail(n3)
    end

    it "removes the head of a list properly" do
      llist.delete(n1)

      puts @head
      puts self.examined_node.data
      puts examined_node
      puts @tail

      expect(llist.head).to eq n2 #Breaks here
      expect(llist.head.next).to eq n3
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n3
    end

    it "removes the middle element of a list properly" do
      llist.delete(n2)
      expect(llist.head).to eq n1
      expect(llist.head.next).to eq n3
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n3
    end

    it "removes the last element of a list properly" do
      llist.delete(n3)
      expect(llist.head).to eq n1
      expect(llist.head.next).to eq n2
      expect(llist.tail).to eq n2
    end
  end
```

Comment: There are too many errors in your code. Make sure you understand, what an _instance variable_ is (the one with @ in the beginning) and how to access it outside of class definition. Also you cannot access _scope local_ variables (like `examined_node`) outside of scope.